# run time error in android devices

Tags: java, android

hi when i am trying to run my app in either emulator or any device it shows us

```
[2011-02-12 17:27:14 - FirstImage] ------------------------------
[2011-02-12 17:27:14 - FirstImage] Android Launch!
[2011-02-12 17:27:14 - FirstImage] adb is running normally.
[2011-02-12 17:27:14 - FirstImage] Performing com.gis.image.FirstImage activity launch
[2011-02-12 17:27:14 - FirstImage] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2011-02-12 17:27:16 - FirstImage] Uploading FirstImage.apk onto device '04038F041500E00A'
[2011-02-12 17:27:27 - FirstImage] Installing FirstImage.apk...
[2011-02-12 17:27:35 - FirstImage] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE
[2011-02-12 17:27:35 - FirstImage] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2011-02-12 17:27:35 - FirstImage] Launch canceled!
```

in logcat it shows as

```
02-12 16:53:53.685: ERROR/CalWidget(3574): Hardware.isScreenOn=false but App.bIsScreenOn=true
02-12 16:54:13.679: ERROR/WeatherEngine(1403): queryString = http://motor.accu-weather.com/widget/motor/weather-data.asp?location=ASI|IN|IN031|MADURAI&metric=1
02-12 16:55:13.056: ERROR/smtp(1485): is not yahoo com
02-12 16:55:14.423: ERROR/smtp(1485): is not yahoo com
02-12 17:19:54.212: ERROR/WeatherEngine(1403): queryString = http://motor.accu-weather.com/widget/motor/weather-data.asp?location=ASI|IN|IN031|MADURAI&metric=1
02-12 17:21:25.775: ERROR/ConnectivityService(1276): connected default network is not mActiveDefaultNetwork!
02-12 17:21:25.783: ERROR/WeatherEngine(1403): queryString = http://motor.accu-weather.com/widget/motor/weather-data.asp?location=ASI|IN|IN031|MADURAI&metric=1
02-12 17:21:26.791: ERROR/WeatherEngine(1403): queryString = http://motor.accu-weather.com/widget/motor/weather-data.asp?location=ASI|IN|IN031|MADURAI&metric=1
02-12 17:24:34.783: ERROR/WeatherEngine(1403): Error Happen
02-12 17:24:34.783: ERROR/WeatherWidgetProvider(1403): failed to get weather info from server
02-12 17:24:39.791: ERROR/WeatherUpdateService(1403): Failed to get Weather info, retryCount=2
02-12 17:24:39.799: ERROR/WeatherEngine(1403): queryString = http://motor.accu-weather.com/widget/motor/weather-data.asp?location=ASI|IN|IN031|MADURAI&metric=1
02-12 17:25:25.463: ERROR/smtp(1485): is not yahoo com
02-12 17:25:26.822: ERROR/smtp(1485): is not yahoo com
02-12 17:31:45.471: ERROR/PackageManager(1276): Couldn't copy package file to temp file.
02-12 17:31:45.580: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3715): ERROR: thread attach failed
02-12 17:32:30.580: ERROR/PackageManager(1276): Couldn't copy package file to temp file.
02-12 17:32:30.689: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3729): ERROR: thread attach failed
```

what is the error pls help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply showing that: `Unable to detect device compatibility` and `Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE`.

1) Make sure that your device is compatible or you have installed the USB drivers correctly.

2) Ensure that your device have a sufficient storage to install the application.

3) Try running your application in `Manual Mode`. To do this just go to `Run>> Run Configurations...` select your `Project`, and in left Window click on `target` tab. Here set the `Deployment Target Selection Mode` to `Manual`. And click on `Run`. A new window will be open `Android Device Chooser`. Here you can run your application on which device you want.